# Javascript solution to get output of add(5)(6) as 1

Tags: javascript

Recently I was going through puzzles for javascript and one question was 
Write a function **add** to output 11 for both the scenarios below.

1. add(5, 6) - Output is 11
2. add(5)(6) - Output is again 11.

I tried a wrapping a function around, but couldn't succeed.

Can you help me understand how to do this?

Thanks.

I tried below code, but I get NaN as output.

```
function add(a){
  function addto(b){
    return a + b;
  }
  return addto();
}

console.log(add(5)(6))
```

Comment: return a function in the add-function.

Comment: You should show us what you tried so far so we get an idea where you are stuck.  Also, this question reminds me of the [jQuery Meta Meme](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/19492#19492).

Comment: Is it supposed to be the same function in both cases?

Comment: @some, yes it is supposed to be the same function

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would do something like this

```
var add = function(a, b) {
    if (arguments.length == 1) {
        return function(b) {
            return a+b;
        }
    }
    else {
        return a+b;
    }
}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vk2ptdvg/)

An alternative solution could be checking if b is undefined.

Comment: @John thanks it works, would you mind explaining please. Does the inner function get the arg b automatically? Sorry was unable to upvote  due to low reputation, but will do when I have enough reps.

Comment: @user3833838 the `b` argument in the inner function is not referring to the `b` which is passed to the `add` function, but to the one passed to the inner function itself.

Comment: @ArnelleBalane, thanks. so if understand it correct, if I have like add(1)(2)(3) and I return function within another function arg 1 will be passed to the main add, arg 2 to the second function, and arg 3 to the 3rd inside 2nd; Am I correct?

Comment: Note that the question asks to write a function `add` whereas you are writing an anonymous function and assigning it to a variable called `add`. Otherwise this is perfectly valid :)

Comment: @user3833838: if you have add(1)(2)(3) then `arguments.length` in the function is evaluated to `1`: the function will return `function(b){ return a+b; }` with the var `a` being equal to `1`. So now with your example we are at `function(b){ return 1+b; }` that is called with the single argument `2`: it will return 3. Then you are calling 3 as if it was a function with the argument `3` from your original `add(1)(2)(3)`. This will trigger a js error.

Answer (score 2):

```
function add(a,b){ return b !== undefined ? a + b : function(b){ return a + b; } }
```

Comment: This might work for `a = 5` and `b = 6`, but what if the value for `b` is `0`? `0` is evaluated as `false` in Javascript.

Comment: Cool one-liner btw :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
function add(a, b) {
  if (b !== undefined) {
    return a + b;
  }
  return function(c) {
    return a + c;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I could implement it for two correctly.

```
function sum(x) {
  if (arguments.length == 2) {
    return arguments[0] + arguments[1];
  } else {
    return function(y) { return x + y; };
  }
}
```